# Module variables are not initialized error inside error type check

Tags: ballerina

The following code generates the proceeding error,

[image]

Error:

```
cannot call a function or method in the same module before all module-level variables are initialized: variable(s) 'capabilityStatement' not initialized(BCE2573)
```

But the same logic inside a `do,on-fail` does not cause the error.

```
final readonly & models:CapabilityStatement capabilityStatement;

function init() {
    CapabilityStatementGenerator capabilityStatementGenerator = new("./resources/resources.json");
    do {
        capabilityStatement = check capabilityStatementGenerator.generate().cloneReadOnly();
    } on fail var err {
        panic error(err.message());
    }
}
```

What Ballerina language logic causes these different scenarios for the same code logic?

NOTE: The image is attached to show where the specific error is caused.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you mentioned related to `do/on-fail` is an erroneous behavior that is being tracked in https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/38530.